# Loading x,y data into a Geodatabase feature class

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I have done this before without problems.  But now, it is not allowing me to load xyz data from excel into a feature class of a geodatabase.  The error message is "the field is not null-able [shape]".  There is a Shape field that has Allow Null Values = No, but, my data does not have "null" values.  Please help and explain to me what this means.

Comment: What tool/procedure are you using to try and load the x,y,z data?  Can you perhaps edit your question to include that detail and a picture of what your x,y,z data looks like.  I'll +1 your question in case you need more rep to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Simple Data Loader (right click Feature Class in the Catalog window), one of the fields in excel might be mapped to the shape field.

Or, there are more records in the Excel sheet than in your feature class.  In which case it is trying to make new features, but without a shape.  This seems the most likely.